# Changing title in uibutton in stackview inside scrollview using swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, padding, uistackview

Could you give me some help please about why paddings for button title isn't working, please?

I have the code below from where I update the button's titles n times. Buttons are inside a horizontal scrollview. Inside scrollview I have a stackview. From outside the scroll, I update the titles and paddings are out from my control.

The problem is the following: if I give a huge title for the button and then I change for a short title, the paddings aren't updated as I determined in the code below.

```
    private func setupActionButtons(index: Int = 0, title: String = "") {
    
    allButtons[index].layer.cornerRadius = allButtons[0].bounds.height/2
    allButtons[index].layer.borderWidth = 1
    allButtons[index].layer.borderColor = UIColor.borderShortcutButton.cgColor
    allButtons[index].setTitleColor(.psGreyValueLabelFilled, for: .normal)
    if title != "" {
        allButtons[index].setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    }
    allButtons[index].titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    allButtons[index].contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 15)
    allButtons[index].imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    
    allButtons[index].imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    allButtons[index].setImage(uiImage, for: .normal)
    allButtons[index].semanticContentAttribute = UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft
    
    allButtons[index].titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: buttonFontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
    
    allButtons[index].tag = index
    allButtons[index].addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleSelectOption(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
}
```

explaining better: when I add title with similar width for two buttons inside the stackview and after that I change the title  for one of the buttons to a less wide, the other button gets with a bigger width with a bigger padding and the other I changed arranges correctly.

Comment: Have you tried  button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true  ?

Comment: Quick test and I'm not seeing any issues. You say *"Buttons are inside a horizontal scrollview view. Inside scrollview I have a stackview."*  Do you mean the buttons are arrangedSubviews of the stackView? If so, is the problem with the way you've configured / constrained the stackView? You need to provide more information.

Comment: @StefanOvomate your suggestion didn't solve

Comment: @DonMag the buttons are arranged inside stackview. I saw no problem with the stackview configuration. The configuration sounds correct.

Comment: @DonMag  I added more description in the end of the answer

Comment: @Marcel - *"I saw no problem with the stackview configuration"* ... well, *something* is wrong, but you have to provide detail to get any help. What is your stack view's **Distribution** set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is setting the stack view's `Distribution` to `Fill Proportionally`

With the stack view set to `Fill` the problem goes away.

As a side note: forget you ever heard about `Fill Proportionally` ... it is the most misunderstood and misused setting for stack views, and unless you know exactly how it works and exactly why you want to use it, you won't get your desired layout.